# Using numpy to calculate the day of of the week for a given dd/mm given the day of the Jan 1st

Tags: python, numpy

I am doing a past paper for exam revision and stuck on this question:

Write a python script to accept from the user the day of the week on which January 1st falls in a particular year, and then to print the day of the week for any other month and day of the month specified by the user.  You may assume that year is not a leap year, that the user types the inputs as the first three letters of any word, and that the following code has previously been defined:

```
import numpy as np
months = np.array(['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'])
ndays = np.array([31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31])
days=np.array(['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'])
```

So I know how to take the input off the user by using the input command so I can create 3 variables:

```
user_Jan_1_day = input('Input the day of the week for Jan 1st: ')
user_month = input('Input the month: ')
user_day = input('Input the day of the month required: ')
```

So say the user said that Jan 1st was 'Sat', and they want the day of the week for 'Mar', '1' i.e. March 1st.

I know that I need to take 31 + 28 + 1. Find the sum = 60.
Take the modulus: 60%7 = 4, and then add four week days to 'Sat' to get 'Wed' as my answer, but how do I do it in Python?

I thought I could do this by using the index of the array so I used

```
a=np.where(months==user_month)
no_of_days = 0
for i in range (a):
    no_of_days =+ ndays[i]
```

but I get an error:  "'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Could someone show me how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following pretty much your exact logic, you can do it like this, with no need to iterate (making sure to get `int(input(...))` for `user_day` rather than the default string input):

```
user_Jan_1_day = input('Input the day of the week for Jan 1st: ')
user_month = input('Input the month: ')
user_day = int(input('Input the day of the month required: '))

m = np.where(months == user_month)[0][0]
d = np.where(days == user_Jan_1_day)[0][0]
# or, maybe more straightforward, since there is only one correct value:
# m = list(months).index(user_month)
# d = list(days).index(user_Jan_1_day)

result = days[(np.sum(ndays[:m]) + user_day + d) % 7]
```

**For example**:

```
>>> user_Jan_1_day = input('Input the day of the week for Jan 1st: ')
Input the day of the week for Jan 1st: Sat
>>> user_month = input('Input the month: ')
Input the month: Mar
>>> user_day = int(input('Input the day of the month required: '))
Input the day of the month required: 1

>>> m = np.where(months == user_month)[0][0]
>>> d = np.where(days == user_Jan_1_day)[0][0]
>>> result = days[(np.sum(ndays[:m]) + user_day + d) % 7]

>>> result
'Wed'
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am grateful to you for spending the time to help me. I knew the logic but did not have the programming technique to get there.  I'll study the answer for a while, pull it apart etc so that I know how in future to use np.where() together with indexing.

Answer (score 1):

The `range()` function takes an integer.  But `a` itself is not an integer.  So try using `range(a[0][0])`:

```
for i in range(range(a[0][0])):
    no_of_days += ndays[i]
no_of_days += int(user_day)
```

Also, your "=+" should be "+=" as shown here.

This gives you the desired date as the number of days into the calendar year.  From there, you can use some modular arithmetic ("`%`") of that with the day for Jan 1st against your `days` array.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I found the np.where function using help but didn't really know how to use it.  I gave up when I found np.where was returning a Tuple.  I don't know I could use those indexing functions to go further.